# PlantronicsHub and a major memory leak

Tags: macos, usb, memory, headphones

I’ve noticed that process SpokesUpdateService  is promoted to the top of my Memory list. Here an example which I captured today (just 24hrs after my last reboot) but on the other day I’ve seen 2.4 GB wasted:

[image]

I've raised a ticket to Plantronics Support but so far nothing constructive.

The only fix I have now is to kill the process after each and every reboot.

Question: any solution you could think of except killing the process?

Comment: Although you've given a lot of background information here, you've not actually asked a question, what you are currently doing is the only solution to the memory leak issue until such time as they fix the problem, you could kill the process using Activity Monitor and it would likely restart it's self if it is being maintained by `launchd` like most Apple services.

Comment: Wondering how that process is started and if there is a way to find in /Library/Startup Items or elsewhere and then delete it. If all it does is run an update daemon it might be safe to just find that StartupItem and trash it.

Answer (score 2):

Though I regularly search for answers here, this is my first post. Please, forgive if I do not match this forum's etiquette.

I fully empathize with your problem. SpokesUpdateService is relentless. For me, it seemed to launch around the same time each day. I knew it was crashing my Late-2011 MBP with Sierra 10.12.6, but today's EtreCheck simple (free) "diagnosis" show this damn SpokesUpdateService caused **113** crashes on November 3rd for me alone. (No wonder my system died and refused to restart for hours!)

Realistically, Plantronics rarely updates the firmware or software for my headset. I can check for updates when I *choose*, not hundreds of times *daily* with SpokesUpdateService.

Here is my simple brute-force solution:

Trash the following three files:

- `com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist`
- Headset Updater (Version 1.1.0 (2015), a Plantronics application
- Plantronics Hub (Version 3.11.52215.23527 (2018) another Plantronics Application.

You might also get away with only trashing `com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist` or editing it (see below).

I deleted these files because com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist seems to call SpokesUpdateService:

[image: com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist on Late-2011MBP]

For good measure, I also trashed the applications "Headset Updater" and "Plantronics Hub." I still have all three in the Trash in case I need them later. Simply putting these three files in the Trash has stopped SpokesUpdateService. I most likely can permanently delete all three and simply re-install the Headset Updater and/or Plantronics Hub if I need/want them.

I have not programmed in decades, but you might try editing `com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist` by deleting "KeepAlive". I say that based on commands at "A launchd Tutorial", http://www.launchd.info (last visited Nov. 9, 2018).

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem I've had on my machine as well (around 60GB usage of VM partition and SpokesUpdateService showed up in Activity Manager under memory consumption as number one). However, newer Versions of the tool doesn't seem to create the mentioned plist anymore. I've just removed ~/Library/Plantronics and the Plantronics Hub.app from Applications and had to kill the application. Seems to be sufficient now :)

Answer (score 1):

The only solutions are:

a. The developer fixes the memory leak.

b. You regularly kill the process.

c. Look for an alternative piece of software / hardware.

The only way to fix a memory leak is to alter the code which only the developer can really do, theoretically you could decompile the application, fix the issue and recompile but that is non-trivial in the extreme unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of the Plantronics Hub and Headset apps and then remove the following files and directories.

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.PlantronicsUpdateService.plist
~/Library/Application Support/Plantronics/*
~/Library/Preferences/Plantronics*
```

Finally, remove/delete `/usr/local/libexec/SpokesUpdateService` and restart.
-- After the above, your system will be free of Poly's junkware. FYI headset still works perfectly without it (Voyager Focus UC)